Assessing effect of tutor in a small study without a control group
Suppose I have the following "experiment" setup.

I am teaching a class of N students. All students were offered access to a TA.
Each student gets K homework assignments throughout the year. On each homework, each student may or may not elicit the help of the TA.
For each student, I record each homework score (e.g., 8/10, where the # of correct answers is not necessarily constant across homeworks) + a binary variable indicating whether they received help from the TA on each homework.
I am interested in using either a Poisson or Binomial regression to understand probability of getting a question correct with / without the TA, while controlling for the student.

Is there any statistical model I could use to estimate the effect of the TA? Does this overall setup fit into any existing framework that I could read more about?

Here, I don't have access to a control group (i.e., another class without a tutor).
In addition, the choice to access the TA is voluntary. Based on what I have read, perhaps I would need to do a two-stage model with an IV?


Do you want the effect of using a TA or the effect of being offered a TA? How are students offered access to a TA?

In my case, they can access the TA via virtual office hours. I think it is fair to say that it is essentially "on-demand" in that if a student needed it, they could receive help (given a relatively small class and ample office hours).

I would like the effect of "using TA." (Since I don't have a control group of "not offered TA", it's not even possible to get the latter, I believe.)

Since you can't force students to use a TA, the effect of using a TA is not a policy-relevant parameter. But perhaps you have good reasons for it to be interesting. To do IV, you need some random variation in encouragement or costs of seeing the TA that is uncorrelated with the error term in the score equation. Weather, some randomness with notifications/reminders, internet outages, maybe some TAs are better about reminding, or the cancellation of things that usually conflict with OHs or TA getting sick. Limits on Zoom attendance.

Without that, the only thing I can see is some bounding exercise about how bad the selection has to be to give you the results once you add controls.
